# How to load features and labels from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use keras with tensorflow to train a network. I've my own digit dataset of myanmar language. I'm trying to develop myanmar digits recognition using neural network using python. I've train.csv file which has a header with format label,pixel0,...,pixel783. I used pandas to load dataframe. But I want to split the dataframe into features and label. Please help me in detail explanation.

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv("mmdigitstrain.csv")
dataframe2 = pd.read_csv("mmdigitstest.csv")

(X_train, y_train) = splitfeaturesandlabelfromdataframe
(X_test, y_test) = splitfeaturesandlabelfromdataframe2
```

Comment: Is the posted solution working for your purposes? Since you didn't provide much information about what operations you further plan to carry out on your data, I was not completely sure, if that solution is what you are looking for. If this answer was helpful, please consider closing the question by accepting the answer; otherwise it would be helpful for others if you would provide more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you are loading your header in your dataframe and you want the header to be separated from the actual data. That would be easy with

Suppose you have a data-array with header line and this becomes your dataframe

```
a=np.array([['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
df=pd.DataFrame(a)

Out: 
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```

Then just rename the columns by your first row and delete that row from the dataframe

```
df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(0)
Out: 
   a  b  c
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```